Overleaf designing graph question
I want to

put a legend at the right-up corner,
add background gridlines for every 5 units,
fix the size of the picture (want to put different data in the same format so that value 30 in this graph is the same length with value 30 in another graph),
wonder if there's a way to download the file in png file from Overleaf.

Thanks a lot in advance.
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    type & before & after   \\
    ICE         & 25.9  & 20.9  \\
    HEV         & 18.9 & 15.9   \\
    PHEV        & 13.2 & 14.3   \\
    BEV         & 23.6 & 26.4  \\
    FCEV        & 18.5  & 22.5  \\
    }\groupaideal 
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            title = Ideal fleet composition (Group A),
            ybar,
            bar width=.75cm,
            width=\textwidth*1.1,
            height=.5\textwidth,
            legend pos = outer north east, 
            legend style = {draw=none, column sep=2mm},
           legend columns = 1, 
            legend style={at={(1,0.5)},
            anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            hide y axis, 
            axis x line*=bottom,
            symbolic x coords={ICE, HEV, PHEV, BEV, FCEV},
            xtick=data,
%            xticklabel style = {align=center, text width=3mm},
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1]\pgfplotspointmeta},
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            every node near coord/.append style = {display text={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            ymin=0,
%            ylabel={\%},
        ]
       \addplot[fill=white, draw=black]table[x=type,y=before]{\groupaideal};
       \addplot[fill=gray, draw=black]table[x=type,y=after]{\groupaideal};
       \legend{Baseline, Informed}
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}


like this ?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    type & before & after   \\
    ICE         & 25.9  & 20.9  \\
    HEV         & 18.9 & 15.9   \\
    PHEV        & 13.2 & 14.3   \\
    BEV         & 23.6 & 26.4  \\
    FCEV        & 18.5  & 22.5  \\
    }\groupaideal 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            title = Ideal fleet composition (Group A),
            ybar,
            bar width=.75cm,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=.5\textwidth,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            legend style={at={(1.05,1)},anchor=north west}, % top-right corner outside
            axis y line*=left, % Y axis line
            axis x line*=bottom,
            ymajorgrids=true, % major gridlines
            grid style=dashed,
            symbolic x coords={ICE, HEV, PHEV, BEV, FCEV},
            xtick=data,
            ymin=0, ymax=35, % max to make plots consistent
            ytick={0,5,...,35}, % every 5 units
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
        ]
       \addplot[fill=white, draw=black]table[x=type,y=before]{\groupaideal};
       \addplot[fill=gray, draw=black]table[x=type,y=after]{\groupaideal};
       \legend{Baseline, Informed}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

You have plenty of examples of the options you're asking on this site...
